# Mathematical operations on packed numerical values

Tags: c#, bit-shift

Given the following code packing four `byte` values into a `uint`.

```
private static void Pack(byte x, byte y, byte z, byte w)
{
    this.PackedValue = (uint)x |
                       ((uint)y << 8) |
                       ((uint)z << 16) |
                       ((uint)w << 24);
}
```

Is it possible to apply mathematical operators like `*, +, / and -` on the value in a manner that it can be unpacked into the correct `byte` equivalent?

EDIT.

To clarify, if I attempt to multiply the value by another packed value

```
uint result  = this.PackedValue * other.PackedValue
```

Then unpack using the following...

```
public byte[] ToBytes()
{
    return new[]
    {
        (byte)(this.PackedValue & 0xFF),
        (byte)((this.PackedValue >> 8) & 0xFF),
        (byte)((this.PackedValue >> 16) & 0xFF),
        (byte)((this.PackedValue >> 24) & 0xFF)
    };
}
```

I get the wrong results.

Here's a full code sample showing the expected and actual result.

```
void Main()
{
    uint x = PackUint(128, 128, 128, 128);
    uint y = (uint)(x * 1.5f);

    byte[] b1 = ToBytes(x);
    x.Dump(); // 2155905152
    b1.Dump(); // 128, 255, 128, 255 RIGHT!
    byte[] b2 = ToBytes(y);
    b2.Dump(); // 0, 192, 192, 192 WRONG! Should be 192, 192, 192, 192

}

// Define other methods and classes here
private static uint PackUint(byte x, byte y, byte z, byte w)
{
    return ((uint)x) |
           ((uint)y << 8) |
           ((uint)z << 16) |
           ((uint)w << 24);
}

public static byte[] ToBytes(uint packed)
{
    return new[]
    {
        (byte)(packed & 0xFF),
        (byte)((packed >> 8) & 0xFF),
        (byte)((packed >> 16) & 0xFF),
        (byte)((packed >> 24) & 0xFF)
    };
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @roryap  I have but I am getting the wrong values back, something is overflowing.

Comment: Ahhh, well I would say you should include that bit in your question.

Comment: Indeed - you should show what you've tried, what you expected, and what happened. A [mcve], basically.

Comment: Use a larger datatype perhaps?

Comment: Combinations of masking+shifting and then back should do, what is the problem?

Comment: Apologies all.. I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you show an actual result, including all input values, and explain how that differs from what you expected?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Done.

Comment: Think of it like this - when you multiply two binary values, each bit "makes a new copy" of the original number shifted to a different bit position. For example, if you multiply 0x15 by 0x03, you get 0x3f which is 0x2a + 0x15 (the first number times 0x02 plus the first number times 0x01). Once a multi-bit number is multiplied by another, bits will get spread out across all possible partial products. This make it impossible to use an 8-bit mask to extract a result from multiplying two 8-bit numbers.

Comment: @BitBank This stuff is a real weakness for me. Your comment definitely helps.

Comment: @JamesSouth have you looked into using SSE?

Comment: I have yes via System.Numerics, but in this situation I'm attempting to keep memory usage and the number of objects down so can't use Vector4 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason it doesn't work for `1.5f` is because floats are not precise enough. Try `1.5d` (for `double`) and your example will work. However this approach is limited to "nice" cases, i.e. those where the result in each byte is guaranteed to be a whole number. A special case is when you multiply by an integer, which will always work so long as none of the four results overflow.

It is also possible to do this for addition and subtraction provided that none of the individual bytes overflow. Obviously any overflow will mess up nearby bytes. This is particularly problematic if you wish to use 2's complement for negative bytes (-128 .. 127) because adding 3 to -2 is also an "overflow" and will mess up the next byte.

Comment: Actually... Come to think about it, the OP wants to multiple 4uints together in one step with no overflow. I think during the 90s intel made a big fuss about how there was a new processor feature for that... https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/11/05/using-system-numerics-vector-for-graphics-programming/

Comment: @Aron Good point. internally in Vector<T> there will be code handling this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

A much nicer solution to your problem is to using Blitting.

```
void Main()
{
    Byte X = 0x13;
    Byte Y = 0x6A;
    Byte Z = 0xA3;
    Byte W = 0x94;

    Foo foo = new Foo(X, Y, Z, W);
    uint i = foo ;

    Foo bar = (uint)(i * 1.5d);

    Console.WriteLine(X * 1.5d == bar.X);
    Console.WriteLine(Y * 1.5d == bar.Y);
    Console.WriteLine(Z * 1.5d == bar.Z);
    Console.WriteLine(W * 1.5d == bar.W);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Foo
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte X;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte Y;

    [FieldOffset(2)]
    public byte Z;

    [FieldOffset(3)]
    public byte W;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint Value;


    public Foo(byte x, byte y, byte z, byte w) : this()
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
        W = w;
    }

    public static implicit operator Foo(uint value)
    {
        return new Foo(){ Value = value };
    }

    public static implicit operator uint(Foo foo)
    {
        return foo.Value;
    }

}
```

We create a new type that, instead of does bit shifting, gives you direct (type safe) access to the memory address that is inside the `uint`.

Comment: But how do you multiply X, Y, Z and W by 1.5 in one go? I think that was OP's question.

Comment: @romkyns `uint i = 1.5f * foo.Value;` But of course your same disclaimer about precision and overflow applies equally. Its just much easier to read.

Comment: @Aron Blitting is certainly a much easier and cleaner approach to managing the struct as a whole.